# Dividing 2 column expression does not give a valid result

Tags: division, obiee

I am doing the following calculation ,

```
SUM(A by Category)/SUM(A + B + C by Category)
```

Both the calculation individually gives values but when division is done the result is always 0. Could anyone help what's wrong with the above expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `A`, `B` and `C` are integers, theirs sums will also be integeres. In that case, Obiee will perform an [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers). Assuming `A`, `B` and `C` are all positive, the denominator will always be larger than the nominator, which explains the zero result. You can resolve this issue by explicitly casting the sums to doubles:

```
CAST(SUM(A by Category) AS DOUBLE)/CAST(SUM(A + B + C by Category) AS DOUBLE)
```

Comment: Hi Mureinik, That works. Thanks for the quick help. :)